# Is there anything like a GLKTableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, glkview

I am currently using a GLKView connected to a GLKViewController in my iOS project to animate the background of my app which works fine. Now I introduced a UITableViewController for displaying some list. I also would like to animate the table view's background similar to the other view controllers. But therefore I need something like a GLKTableViewController, but this doesn't exist.

Somebody any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did implement the most important `UITableViewController` functionalities myself. Basically it's very simple, just implement the following two protocols/interfaces:

- UITableViewDelegate
- UITableViewDataSource

... with their corresponding implementations in the *.m file.

Hope this helps also other people. Regards.